# At what stage / step of development do we start to contemplate on non-self?

Tags: meditation-insight, anatman

List below is extracted form Kimattha Sutta noting how skillful virtues lead step-by-step to the consummation of arahantship.

The question is does skillful virtue require knowledge of non-self or knowledge of non-self is achieved at step 8 when one contemplate on impermanence / conditioned nature of all things including serenity and pleasure one get from virtuous act?

1. Skillful virtues
2. freedom from remorse
3. joy
4. rapture
5. serenity
6. pleasure
7. concentration
8. knowledge & vision of things as they actually are
9. disenchantment
10. dispassion
11. knowledge & vision of release
12. consummation of arahantship

Answer (score 1):

Whatever that is unsatisfactory is not self. Whatever is impermanent is not satisfactory. This is a realisation by direct experience not a form of contemplation. This realisation happens at the stage of "knowledge & vision of things as they actually" which in turn triggers the next stage.

Answer (score 0):

'*Knowledge & vision of things as they actually are*' is the complete contemplation of not-self (although not-self can be observed in some ways when concentration starts to develop).

Answer (score 0):

An individual who wants to get into the practise Saddhamma in its truest sense needs to be grounded in Sila. Better still is to have sila-visuddhi (purification of virtue), once Saddha (Confidence) is firmly instilled within. The mind never leans towards kusala kamma (wholesome volitional actions) without saddha (faith and confidence. This is true also in the case of effort to achieve sila-visuddhi (purification of virtue), and in the study of the sacred texts.  Sila-visuddhi (purification of virtue) resembles the enclosure  as a defense against outside forces.

One who is established in Sila and comes to Saddha, sees things in their proper perspective. i.e. in the light of Anichcha (Impermanence), Dukka (Suffering), and Anatta (Absence of “I”). This firm basis is a part and parcel of his personality and remains with him all the time.